# Repeat link with $_GET

Tags: php, select, mysqli, href

Fairly new and inexperienced with PHP, and I'm stuck.

I have a feature that creates a new sub page that is related to a main page, eg. main page 1 has sub page 1 a, 1b and 1c, and main page 2 has sub page 2a, 2b, 2c and so forth. You gain access to the given sub pages through links in a menu on each of the main pages. I hope you're still with me here.

I have succeeded in getting the menu to link to one of the created sub pages, but what I now need is to get a link dynamically created in the menu whenever I create a new sub page. Main pages and their "id" is connected to the related sub pages via the column "mainid" that corresponds to eachother (eg. index.php?id=5&mainid=5)

The link menu is created by using $_GET.

I have this page: localhost/site/index.php?id=1&mainid=1 with the following code that i'm struggling with:

```
<table width="90%" border="0" cellpadding="5"><tbody>
<tr>
  <td>
  <?php 

  $id = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM page_content WHERE mainid =" . $_GET['mainid'])->fetch_object()->id; 
  $name = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM page_content WHERE mainid =" . $_GET['mainid'])->fetch_object()->name;


  ?>

  <a href="index.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&mainid=<?php echo $_GET['mainid']; ?>">

  <?php

print $name;

?></a></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

This creates a link to content of the sub page. The content of this sub page is stored in id=10 and mainid=5 (thus creating the link index.php?id=10&mainid=5

So far so good.

But how do I get links to be dynamically created on a main page whenever I create a new sub page belonging to that given main page?

Help is much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You're wide open to SQL injections. Not good.

Comment: Basicly what you want is to build up your menu based on the results from your database. Query the database and loop through the results adding a menu item to your menu on each loop. Unfortunetely I always struggle with mysqli() and therefor work with PDO() instead. So I can't give you a good answer / example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are tying to do, but i guess you want to make a loop from database.

To do that, you have to modify your code because right now is not safe, and not good.

use this one instead:

```
<table width="90%" border="0" cellpadding="5"><tbody>
<tr>
  <?php
  /* create a prepared statement */
  $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,name FROM page_content WHERE mainid = ?");
  /* bind parameters  */
  $query->bind_param("i", $_GET['mainid']);
  $query->execute();

  $menu_result = $query->get_result();

  /* now you can fetch the results into an array */
  while ($menu = $menu_result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo <<<HTML
<td>
    <a href="index.php?id={$menu['id']}&mainid={$_GET['mainid']}">{$menu['name']}</a>
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
HTML;
  }

   ?>

</tr>

   </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: That worked. It does exactly what I needed it to do: making a link to a created record in the database by using columns id and mainid to fetch. Thanks a bunch!